# r plotly chart based on multiple columns

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a df which can have 2 or more columns with the first one `month` always fixed.I am trying to plot them using plotly r. As of now it has three columns: month,apple,orange. Based on analysis it can have another column banana. Below is the code I am using right now but it even takes the column month for y-axis. How do I fix this:

```
> sample_test
    month apple orange
2  Aug-17     2      1
3  Dec-17     2      1
4  Feb-18     2      1
5  Jan-18     2      1
6  Jul-17     2      1
7  Jun-17     2      1
8  May-17     2      1
9  Nov-17     2      1
10 Oct-17     2      1
11 Sep-17     2      1

p<- plot_ly(sample_test, x = sample_test$month,  name = 'alpha', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = 'rgb(24, 205, 12)', width = 4)) %>% 
  layout(#title = "abbb",
    xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
    yaxis = list (title = "Percentage"))

for(trace in colnames(sample_test)){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)
}
p
```

The output looks like this :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
sample_test <- read.table(
  text = '    month apple orange
2  Aug-17     2      1
  3  Dec-17     2      1
  4  Feb-18     2      1
  5  Jan-18     2      1
  6  Jul-17     2      1
  7  Jun-17     2      1
  8  May-17     2      1
  9  Nov-17     2      1
  10 Oct-17     2      1
  11 Sep-17     2      1'
)
sample_test$month <- as.Date(paste('01', sample_test$month, sep = '-'), format = '%d-%b-%y')
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(sample_test, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = 'rgb(24, 205, 12)', width = 4)) %>% 
  layout(#title = "abbb",
    xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
    yaxis = list (title = "Percentage", tickformat = '%'))
for(trace in colnames(sample_test)[2:ncol(sample_test)]){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(x = sample_test[['month']], y = sample_test[[trace]], name = trace)
}
p
```

[image]

There are couple of things to note here -

1. While dealing with dates, it's best to format them as dates. This can save a lot of headache later on. It is also useful as most if not all functions that require dealing with dates have methods built to handle them.
2. While adding traces in a `for` loop, always reference the vector to be plotted explicitly like `data$vector` or `data[['vector']]` and not like `y = ~vector`, because `plotly` for some reason ends up plotting just one trace over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a trace for the first `y` element, which will give you your raw counts. Next you can add a format for your y-axis using `tickformat`, which will convert to percentages.

```
sample_test <- data.frame(month = c("Aug-17", "Dec-17", "Feb-18"), apple = c(2,2,2), orange = c(1,1,1))
p <- plot_ly(sample_test, x = sample_test$month, y = ~apple, name = 'alpha', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'rgb(24, 205, 12)', width = 4)) %>% 
     layout(xaxis = list(title = "Time")) %>% 
     layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = "%", title = "Percentage"))
```

Although for some reason this appears to just multiply by 100 and add a `%` label for some reason, rather than actually calculate a percentage. From this [SO answer, looks like that's all it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638590/plotly-in-r-format-axis-tick-labels-to-percentage). I don't really use plotly, but in ggplot you can do this if you reshape your data to long and map your categorical variable (in this case fruit) as a percent.

[image: Plotly plot]

Edit: per OP's comment, removed month from being traced.

```
p <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = "%", title = "Percentage"))
colNames <- names(sample_test)
colNames <- colNames[-which(colNames == 'month')]
for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(data = sample_test, x = ~ month, y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace)
  print(paste0("~`", trace, "`"))
}
p
```

[image: Edited plot]

Comment: you are getting month as a trace

Comment: It was not clear from your question you did not want that. Edited to reflect.